# kml blocks elevation service

Tags: google-maps, kml, infowindow, elevation

I have a Google Maps elevation service (for my Geography of Pennsylvania students) that works fine with point clicks on Google's basemaps.  I would like to add a kml layer showing PA counties.  When I add it, the elevation infowindow no longer displays.  Is there a way to add the kml but suppress its click response so that the elevation response shows?

Current code (partial):

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: centerOfPA,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var paCounties = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mapmaker.millersville.edu/arcgis/services/PAcounties/MapServer/KmlServer', {suppressInfoWindows: true});
paCounties.setMap(map);

  // Create an ElevationService
elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();

  // Add a listener for the click event and call getElevation on that location
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', getElevation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either suppress click events on the [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) (clickable: false) or handle the click events and call the elevation service (with the latLng from that [click event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlMouseEvent)).

[Here is a working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_elevation_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/PAcounties_kmz.zip)